# Can't get the last array in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

```js
const search = await spot.search(request, {
  limit: 3,
  type: ['track']
});
search.tracks.items.forEach(song => {
  let tableArtists = []
  song.artists.forEach(artist => {
    if (song.artists[0].name == artist.name) return tableArtists.push(artist.name)
    if (song.artists[song.artists.length].name == artist.name) return tableArtists.push(" & " + artist.name)
    tableArtists.push(", " + artist.name)
  })
  console.log(song.name + " - " + tableArtists.join(" "))
})
```

This code is supposed to get all the artists in a song, and the last one starts with an `&` symbol. At the moment, it will not get the name of the last artist. Why? FYI: song.artists.last() does not work either.

Comment: Please provide a sample of the data from `search` and expected results as per [mre]

Answer (score 0):

last element's index of song.artists array is not `song.artists.length` but `song.artists.length - 1`

replace

`if (song.artists[song.artists.length].name == artist.name) return tableArtists.push(" & " + artist.name)`

with

`if (song.artists[song.artists.length - 1].name == artist.name) return tableArtists.push(" & " + artist.name)`

Answer (score -2):

Search Response:

```json
Track {
  availableMarkets:
   [ 'AD',
     'AE',
     'AG',
     'AL',
     'AM',
     'AO',
     'AR',
     'AT',
     'AZ',
     'BA',
     'BB',
     'BD',
     'BF',
     'BG',
     'BH',
     'BI',
     'BJ',
     'BN',
     'BO',
     'BR',
     'BS',
     'BW',
     'BY',
     'BZ',
     'CA',
     'CH',
     'CI',
     'CL',
     'CM',
     'CO',
     'CR',
     'CV',
     'CW',
     'CY',
     'CZ',
     'DE',
     'DJ',
     'DK',
     'DM',
     'DO',
     'DZ',
     'EC',
     'EE',
     'EG',
     'FI',
     'FJ',
     'FM',
     'FR',
     'GA',
     'GB',
     'GD',
     'GH',
     'GM',
     'GN',
     'GQ',
     'GR',
     'GT',
     'GW',
     'HK',
     'HN',
     'HR',
     'HT',
     'HU',
     'ID',
     'IE',
     'IL',
     'IN',
     'IS',
     'IT',
     'JM',
     'JO',
     'JP',
     'KE',
     'KG',
     'KH',
     'KM',
     'KN',
     'KR',
     'KW',
     'KZ',
     'LA',
     'LB',
     'LC',
     'LK',
     'LR',
     'LS',
     'LT',
     'LV',
     'MA',
     'MC',
     'MD',
     'ME',
     'MG',
     'MK',
     'ML',
     'MN',
     'MO',
     'MR',
     'MT',
     'MU',
     ... 55 more items ],
  discNumber: 1,
  duration: 165440,
  explicit: false,
  externalUrls:
   { spotify: 'https://open.spotify.com/track/483XiZ5o13Cc1zoWV7jGml' },
  href: 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/tracks/483XiZ5o13Cc1zoWV7jGml',
  id: '483XiZ5o13Cc1zoWV7jGml',
  name: 'Gecko (Overdrive) - Radio Edit',
  previewUrl:
   'https://p.scdn.co/mp3-preview/9ed94074e04a78652aecf9f4c58ebffe9cd16fbd?cid=ac37a89f1e77422e955b85f07d8a6cdb',
  trackNumber: 1,
  type: 'track',
  uri: 'spotify:track:483XiZ5o13Cc1zoWV7jGml',
  playable: undefined,
  local: false,
  externalIds: { isrc: 'CYA111400063' },
  popularity: 70,
  restrictions: null }
```

Comment: This isn't an answer. It's also not valid javascript for anyone to use to test your code with. Edit the question with valid response data and delete this answer. You can also remove irrelevant properties